# Remove Emoji in GitHub Desktop First Commit

Tags: git, emoji, git-commit, github-for-windows, github-desktop

Whenever I create a new repository in the GitHub Desktop app, it makes an initial commit with the message ":boom::camel: Added .gitattributes & .gitignore files".

This is fine, EXCEPT for the emoji. How can I permanently disable the emoji being included in messages I don't ever type? I want my messages to look professional, but I don't want to stop using the GitHub Desktop App.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I made several commits after the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

You can ammend the commit locally and edit the commit message (not sure if the desktop app has this feature), then force put it. The other option is to generate the repository without the initial commit and add the files yourself with a sane commit message.

Comment: I am new to Github Desktop. How do I generate a new repository in the app without the initial commit message?

Comment: You can generate the repository on github.com web site. There will be an option if you want the initial commit or not. If you create it without initial commit you can clone it in the app. You could also use `git init` command line. In the Github app there is an option "gitignore: none", maybe that skips the initial commit?